# How do I make a method that accepts multiple lambda expressions as parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I'm trying to make my own Extension method that can take any number of lambda expressions, but It seems to choke any time I add more than one expression.

Here is the method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString _RouteButton<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, string label, string controller, string action, params Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>[] parameters)
{
   var test = parameters;
   return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

Here is the markup that calls it successfully:

```
<%: Html._RouteButton("details", "Health", "SystemDetails", m=>m.Id)%>
```

Here is the markup that errors:

```
<%: Html._RouteButton("details", "Health", "SystemDetails", m=>m.Id, m=>m.Status)%>
```

Here is the error:

> The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments explicitly

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are the types of Id and Status?

Comment: Instead of taking multiple Lambdas to get multiple params, could you just use one to return a new anonymous object with the necessary fields?

`<%: Html._RouteButton("details", "Health", "SystemDetails", m=> new { id= m.Id, status = m.Status})%>`

Comment: @ShaneA You cannot do that because you cannot define a type for the parameter if anonymous types are involved.

Comment: Shane, I actually have an override that does that, but for the sake of simplicity I'd like to pass lambda expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to get this on the site in case someone was attempting something similar.

The code builds a route form. To do this it needs the **name** of the property and its **value**.

```
public static void _RouteButton<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, string text, string controller, string action, params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] parameters)
{
    using (htmlHelper.BeginRouteForm("Default", new { controller = controller, action = action }))
    {
        foreach (Expression<Func<TModel, object>> p in parameters)
        {
            MemberExpression me;
            switch (p.Body.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Convert:
                case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked:
                    var ue = p.Body as UnaryExpression;
                    me = ((ue != null) ? ue.Operand : null) as MemberExpression;
                    break;
                default:
                    me = p.Body as MemberExpression;
                    break;
            }
            string name = me.Member.Name;
            string value = p.Compile()(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model).ToString();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(htmlHelper.Hidden(name, value).ToHtmlString());
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<input type='submit' value='" + text + "' />");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Let's simplify:

```
using System;
class P
{
    static void M<R>(params Func<R>[] p) {}
    static void N(int i, string s, decimal m)
    {
        M(()=>i, ()=>s); // fails
        M(()=>i, ()=>s.Length); // succeeds
        M(()=>i, ()=>m); // succeeds
    }
}
```

Now is it clear why your program fails?

In my program each call attempts to infer R. In the first call, R is inferred to be both int and string, and therefore inference fails because there is no type that is both int and string.  In the second, R is inferred to be int and... int again! which succeeds because int matches all bounds. In the third, R is inferred to be int and decimal, which succeeds, because every int can be implicitly converted to decimal, so decimal is a good inference.

Id and Status are probably properties with incompatible types. If you want to do this then one of the types inferred must be *the best type*.

Note that C# never says "oh, I see you inferred bounds of Dog, Cat and Fish, so I guess you meant Animal".  C# rather says "none of Dog, Cat or Fish are clearly the best bound, so I don't know what you meant; please specify it explicitly".

Comment: I can see the pattern to the failure, but it seems the type would be Func<R> not string, int, or decimal. Why would .Net conduct validation that is more strict than the method signature?

Comment: @Nathaniel: R isn't a type. R is a *placeholder* that must be *filled in* with a type. (The same way that a parameter isn't a value, a parameter is a location that must be supplied with a value, called the argument.) The compiler is telling you that it cannot work out what type you intend to substitute in for R.

Comment: @Nathaniel: another way to look at it is that C# is attempting to figure out *what the intended method signature is*.  Is it `M(Func<int>[])` or `M(Func<string>[])` or what? Don't think of generic methods as methods; think of them as patterns from which you can create methods by supplying type arguments.

Comment: What is the benefit of .Net determining the type of the parameter, if it is not going to do anything with the parameter?

I could understand if these was a compiler restriction, but it is a run time error.

Does this perhaps have to do with the automatic marshaling that .Net does? Does it need to know the type to marshal properly?

Comment: @Nathaniel: It is a compilation time restriction, not a run-time error. It has nothing to do with marshalling.  Look at it this way. When you have a method `M<T>` and you call it, you are *required* to give a type argument. You are *required* to say `M<int>`, the same way as you are *required* to say `List<int>` when you make a new list. It has to be a list *of something*. The method has to be a method *of something*. Now, as a courtesy, if you omit the `<int>`, the compiler will attempt a guess at what you meant. If the compiler is unable to guess, then it tells you that.

Comment: But you are *required* to either say *what the method type arguments are*, or to *provide enough information that the compiler can guess at what you meant to say*.  You're doing neither, so you get a compile-time error.

Comment: It is a run time error, but I guess we both forgot that this is because the code is in markup and not compiled until run time. I forgot the method was called from markup, so that lead me down that erroneous trail.

Comment: @Nathaniel: It's still a compile time error, not a run time error.

Answer (score 4):

Eric Lippert's answer explains what the problem is. I would add how to actually solve it: you most likely don't need the lambda to return the type of the property, you just want to get the expression tree to examine the properties. So, what you can do is to change the type from `Func<TModel, TProperty>` to `Func<TModel, object>` (and remove the `TProperty` type parameter). Since all normal types in C# are implicitly convertible to `object`, your code will compile and run fine with this change

Comment: That is exactly the solution that I ended up with. I have to wait a few more hours before I am permitted to post it, but I will post it then.

Answer (score -1):

@eric-lippert explained "why it won't work" given your example. The types of the properties passed in each expression are not the same.

Change the signature of the extension method to only specifiy TModel as as the generic will help resolve the issue. In addition, specifyobject in place of TProperty for the expression function.

**Extension Method**

```
public static MvcHtmlString _RouteButton<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
                                                 params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] parameters)
{
    var test = parameters;
    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

**ASP/Razor**

```
<%: Html._RouteButton(m=>m.Id, m=>m.Status)%>
@Html._RouteButton(m=>m.Id, m=>m.Status)
```